# convert audio to bytes without recording c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing a c# Windows Form. My intention is to create a form that can make calls to other PCs in the same network. 
So far I have found solutions that record the audio from my microphone and then convert it to bytes and send it using Tcp sockets. The thing is, is there a way to directly convert the audio to bytes and send it through a socket without recording the audio in a file and then send it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please tell me what do you mean by "make calls to other PC?

Comment: Im sure there is a way to stream the audio, as many applications do exactly that.

Comment: NAudio probably has a streaming api, but so have others. What have you found already?

Comment: Are you wanting to stream the audio (ie transmit it live) or do you want to save it to memory for later use rather than saving it to a file and then reading that into memory?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI for example, I open a socket in both ends and speak to a specific port and the other listens and vice versa. I have managed to do it with Naudio. The thing is, I had to record audio to a file and then convert it to Bytes and send it. I am trying to Stream audio without recording at all.

Comment: @Chris Trasmit it live without recording at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

would converting the record to a memorystream be what your looking for?
if so you want this [How to record audio using naudio onto byte[] rather than file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384493/how-to-record-audio-using-naudio-onto-byte-rather-than-file)

You can then write the stream to a tcpsocket. (you could write the thing direct to networkstream but i would consider it bad practice)

It would be wise to write samplerate*3 just in case of lantcy issues.